# Button inside border using CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

How can I make a button with an inner border, where if I hover over the button, the inner border will shrink?

[image: f]

```
.btnTest {
    color: #f5f5f5;
    background-color: #000000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1;
    -moz-border-radius: 1;
    border-radius: 1px;
    /*border: 0;*/
    border-bottom: 3px solid green;
    /*-webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 2;
    border-radius: 2px;*/
}

.btnTest:hover {
    color: #f5f5f5;
    background-color: #000000;

    -webkit-border-radius: 1;
    -moz-border-radius: 1;
    border-radius: 1px;

    border-bottom: 2px solid green;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    /*border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;*/
}
```

Comment: Please post your fiddle link also...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `box-shadow`?

```css
.btnTest {
      height: 40px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #f5f5f5;
      background-color: #000000;
      -webkit-border-radius: 1;
      -moz-border-radius: 1;
      border-radius: 1px;
      box-shadow: inset 0 -6px green;
}

.btnTest:hover {
      box-shadow: inset 0 -4px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="btnTest">button</div>
```

Comment: Yeah  Aaron! this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!